# The terminal is stuck at "WARNING - datasets.builder - Using custom data configuration default-{hashed_id}"

Tags: pytorch, nlp, gpu

I try to use SimCSE's code for training,
Source: https://github.com/princeton-nlp/SimCSE/blob/main/run_sup_example.sh
Follow the instructions to install after python3.7 and cuda10.1:

Train with the following command:

```
bash run_sup_example.sh
```

**The terminal is stuck at "WARNING - datasets.builder - Using custom data configuration default-{hashed_id}"**

--
<run_sup_example.sh>

```
NUM_GPU=4

# Randomly set a port number
# If you encounter "address already used" error, just run again or manually set an available port id.
PORT_ID=$(expr $RANDOM + 1000)

# Allow multiple threads
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8

# Use distributed data parallel
# If you only want to use one card, uncomment the following line and comment the line with "torch.distributed.launch"
# python train.py \
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node $NUM_GPU --master_port $PORT_ID train.py \
    --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased \
    --train_file data/nli_for_simcse.csv \
    --output_dir result/my-sup-simcse-bert-base-uncased \
    --num_train_epochs 3 \
    --per_device_train_batch_size 128 \
    --learning_rate 5e-5 \
    --max_seq_length 32 \
    --evaluation_strategy steps \
    --metric_for_best_model stsb_spearman \
    --load_best_model_at_end \
    --eval_steps 125 \
    --pooler_type cls \
    --overwrite_output_dir \
    --temp 0.05 \
    --do_train \
    --do_eval \
    --fp16 \
    "$@"
```

1. It can be trained normally on a server, so I deduce that this program is no problem
2. But in another Server can not train, The terminal is stuck at "WARNING - datasets.builder - Using custom data configuration default-{hashed_id}"

The memory usage of the GPU has not changed. I am not sure why. Please help me! QQ